# COUNT duplicate e-mails and show count while ignoring case

Tags: mysql

I have a table with duplicate e-mails which looks like this

```
email
-------------------
parrick01@yahoocom
johnsmith@gmailcom 
annabella@gmailcom
JohnSmith@gmailcom
johnsmith@gmailcom
JOHNSMITH@gmailcom
ANNABELLA@gmailcom
patrick12@gmailcom
```

The closest I could come up with is this:

```
SELECT
    a.email as 'email',
    z.email_count
FROM
    customer a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            email as email,
            count(lower(email)) AS email_count
        FROM
            customer
        GROUP BY
            email
    ) z on a.email = z.email
```

Which would produce results like so:

```
email               | email_count
---------------------------------
parrick01@yahoocom | 1
johnsmith@gmailcom | 1
annabella@gmailcom | 1
JohnSmith@gmailcom | 1
johnsmith@gmailcom | 1
JOHNSMITH@gmailcom | 1
ANNABELLA@gmailcom | 1
patrick12@gmailcom | 1
```

I want to only show all duplicate e-mails, like this:

```
email               | email_count
---------------------------------
johnsmith@gmailcom | 4
annabella@gmailcom | 2
JohnSmith@gmailcom | 4
johnsmith@gmailcom | 4
JOHNSMITH@gmailcom | 4
ANNABELLA@gmailcom | 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table expression to precompute the duplicate email counts.

For example:

```
select
  a.email,
  b.email_count
from customer a
join (
  select lower(email) as lower_email, count(*) as email_count
  from customer
  group by lower(email)
) b on lower(a.email) = b.lower_email
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function

```
select 
  email, count(*) over (partition by lower(email)) email_count
from t
```